# How to properly add Key-Value Observer to my button?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, key-value-observing

I have a UITableViewCell file and inside of it I do:

```
var followers: FollowersModel? {
    didSet { 
        self.followerButton.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "followerButtonTapped", options: .New, context: &kvoContext)
    }
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    print(keyPath)
}
```

where

```
private var kvoContext = 0
```

So, I want: When I click on the button in those Cell it'll run function from the ViewController. But on click on my button does not print anything.

It's my first time with KVOs, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, KVO does not work like that. What `- addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` does is register observer to receive KVO notifications when property changed. In your case I suppose "followerButtonTapped" is not a property. [Registering for observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:)

To handle button tapped you need to add target like this (or in IB):

```
cell.followerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.onFollowerButtonTap(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And add method to your view controller:

```
func onFollowerButtonTap(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

To get the model object for this button you can use this extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func indexPathForView(view: UIView) -> NSIndexPath? {
        let hitPoint = view.convertPoint(CGPoint.zero, toView: self)
        return indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    }
}
```